# The ability to underline?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

I always wondered why there is no underline ability?

Not even using HTML tags

Is this by design for all SE sites, or just a handful (or just AE?)

Please could we have an underline feature added?

Comment: Underlining is usually only used as fall back when there is no way make text bold or italic. It is usually recognized as bad practise from a typesetting point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flavor of Markdown that Stack Exchange uses doesn't support this.

I would be against it in any case. Underlines are very commonly understood to indicate links when on web sites. You mess with this very basic and well-understood UI element at your peril. (I can't tell you how many times I've been on some web site and tried to click underlined text and nothing happened.)

See also: [Why can we format text with bold and italic but not underline?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-sideline-the-underline)

It's been brought up before and unless you can devise a compelling *new* argument it's not going to be implemented.

Comment: Ah, thanks. For some reason, I don't feel right if I don't underline headings...